# Visual Studio 2015 publish failed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ftp, publish

My Visual Studio 2015 project would not publish via FTP after it worked for almost a year.  It is .NET Framework 4.5.2.

After a compiler update a couple of weeks ago, I would sometimes have to try publishing twice before it would update.  Last night after a Windows Update, it wouldn't publish at all.

Solution:

- I ran diagnostics and discovered that Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.6.1 was throwing an error, even though the project was able to successfully Rebuild.
- I uninstalled compiler 2.6.1 and installed 2.0.1 (compatible with .NET 4.5.2) and was able to publish via FTP without any problems or errors.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: I had the same problem with VS 2k15. Now i use VS 2k17 and there is no problem with latest version of Microsoft.Net.Compilers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled compiler 2.6.1 and installed 2.0.1 (compatible with .NET 4.5.2) and was able to publish via FTP without any problems or errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The project was building okay but when I published it Azure send me errors.

My project target .NET framework was 4.6.2 version and I was upgrading Nugget packages, unfortunatelly I upgraded my .NET Compilers to last version and it wasnt compatible to my target .NET version.You should be able to see it here:

[Description of .NET Compilers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AWZe.png)

[My target framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYqS3.png)

I fixed it by downgrading .NET Compilers to a version compatible to my .NET Framework (In my case, to use 4.6.2 framework I need to use .NET Compiller 2.10).